# To change the default bootstrap css values with less

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, less

I'm doing a site with `HTML5` and`bootstrap-less`nothing works normally but I needed to change some colors in the `navbar` menu and I know I can do this through`variables.less` inside this file I navigate to the menus where I copy all the code related to the menu that I want to edit and paste in my `.less` file but it does not work I do not want to have to use`! important` to change the menu being that I know I can do this by only variables in the `less` that comes in the bootsrap this is the`less` code of the menu
LESS:

```
@navbar-default-color:             #fff;
@navbar-default-bg:                #f8f8f8;
@navbar-default-border:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);

//* Navbar links*/
@navbar-default-link-color:                #fff;
@navbar-default-link-hover-color:          #fff;
@navbar-default-link-hover-bg:             transparent;
@navbar-default-link-active-color:         #fff;
@navbar-default-link-active-bg:            darken(@navbar-default-bg, 6.5%);
@navbar-default-link-disabled-color:       #fff;
@navbar-default-link-disabled-bg:          transparent;

/* Navbar brand label*/
@navbar-default-brand-color:               @navbar-default-link-color;
@navbar-default-brand-hover-color:         darken(@navbar-default-brand-color, 10%);
@navbar-default-brand-hover-bg:            transparent;

/* Navbar toggle*/
@navbar-default-toggle-hover-bg:           #fff;
@navbar-default-toggle-icon-bar-bg:        #fff;
@navbar-default-toggle-border-color:       #fff;
```

even though I change the values it does not change on my site notice that I left everything white to do a test and my site does not change:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

this is my menu:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="box-menu">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        <img src="assets/images/logo-santa-clara-eco.png" class="img-responsive" alt="Santa Clara EcoResort" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline contact-info">
                            <li class="list"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>Rod SP 215 Km 197 - Dourado - SP</a></li>
                            <li class="list"><a href="tel:551633454004"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>+55 (16) 3345 4004</a></li>
                            <li class="list"><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/contato.php"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>Contato</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <img src="assets/images/logo_top.png" class="img-responsive logos-inline" alt="Tripadvisor L'OCITANE ABR" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
                <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav list-nav-menu">
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/index.php"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/resort.php">resort</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/acomodacoes.php" id="question" >acomodações</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/gastronomia.php">gastronomia</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/atividades.php">atividades</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/spa.php">SPA</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/eventos/outdoor-training.php">eventos</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/monitora/monitora-clubinho.php">monitoria</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/pacotes/final-de-semana.php">pacotes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/programacao.php">programação</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                          <a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/contato.php" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Contato <b class="caret"></b></a>
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="http://santaclaraecoresort.com.br/localizacao.php">Localização</a></li>
                          </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right list-inline social-networks hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-youtube" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" target="_BLANK"><i class="fa fa-tripadvisor" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

I'm importing everything normal ``` bootstrap``css ``` and`js` together with `jquery` and I'm doing`@ import` right away

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

my app.less file with the import:

```
@import "../vendor/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less";
@import "app.css";
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

image of my variables with the colors I need to change, I copied the variables from the `variables.less` file and added it to my`app.less` I changed the colors they appear on the console but they do not overwrite.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

my `less` file with the color changes (remembering that this is a copy of the`variables.less` file)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Load your Less variables after Bootstrap's ones.

Comment: @MiquelAl.Vicens as well ? I did not understand.

Comment: Can you put in a live code editor?